# Lightweight PHP CRUD

Tags: php, pdo, crud

I am looking for a PHP CRUD solution, that if possible has the following chatacteristics:

- only generates CRUD queries and not HTML forms
- is robust, but lightweight
- can handle table relationships
- uses PDO or similar Db abstraction layer

I am still interesting in hearing views, even if a solution doesn't cover all of the above

Comment: For framework-agnostic UI solution, see Agile UI, it has all of the above: http://ui.agiletoolkit.org/demos/crud.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.phalconphp.com.

The ORM is written in C and can provide all the CRUD operations through its own SQL hybrid language but using PDO in the background.

Comment: Does Phalcon yet do crud? I don't think so, even the devs try hard to push any blurp in there instead of keeping small.